# Firebase : Manage one to many relationship in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing one application to manage a basic account, which has Firebase as a backend. But in the Firestore structure, I am a bit confused that how should I manage **transactions** for **account** in Cloud Firestore.

As I am coming from a SQL background, I am very confused to do so.

For one account I will have many transactions containing credit or debit data.

Can anyone suggest me some basic and effective way to implement this?

This is my existing implementation but, for every account, I want to add transaction.

**By transactions I mean just like bank transactions, just as your passbook.**

I want to add the above data in the transaction.

```
amount -> how much amount I have credited/debited

date -> credit/debit date

details -> date of transaction

is_credit -> bool for this account is credit or debit

balance -> final balance after this transaction
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly would you like to add/update?

Comment: I want to add transactions for every account. As you can see there is one account, for this account i want to add multiple transactions like credit, debit, balance, date etc etc.

Comment: What do you mean through "transactions"? Do you need more properties or more objects inside your document? How does a transaction look like?

Comment: Yes exactly, i want to add more properties in this account,
Transactions like bank passbook transactions for your account.

Comment: How exactly does a transaction look like? Please provide a concrete. example.

Comment: Sorry for communication gap, I have updated answer,
If you are still confused please let me know.

Comment: I see, I will write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add "transactions" to an existing account, you have two options. Since a transaction is an object with different properties (amount, date, details, is_credit, balance), you can add such an object into an array of "transactions", that can be a property within your account document. Your schema should look like this:

```
Firstore-root
  |
  --- accounts (collection)
        |
        --- pTSc...0Onp
              |
              --- address: "1200"
              |
              --- //Other details
              |
              --- transactions (array)
                    |
                    --- 0
                    |   |
                    |   --- amount: 300
                    |   |
                    |   --- date: February 28, 2020 at 3:37:59 PM UTC+3
                    |   |
                    |   --- details: "Transaction details"
                    |   |
                    |   --- is_credit: true
                    |   |
                    |   --- balance: 1200
                    |
                    --- 1
                        |
                        --- amount: 100
                        |
                        --- date: February 28, 2020 at 5:21:22 PM UTC+3
                        |
                        --- details: "Other transaction details"
                        |
                        --- is_credit: false
                        |
                        --- balance: 3600
```

This solution will work only as long as you are 100% sure that the size of the document will stay within the [1Mib limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

If that's not the case, then you should consider adding those `Transaction` objects within a subcollection that can exist within the `Account` document. In that case, there is no limitation about the number of documents that can be added to that subcollection.